# Can't save data to SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, vb.net

I'm quite confused why the data that I added was not saved to the database.

While my program is running there are no problems in updating the data that is shown in `DataGridView` but when I close the program, the added data disappears.

I tried to show table data but there were no new data added. Can you tell me what is the problem?

This is my code:

```
Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
Dim adaptor As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
Dim dataset As New DataSet

con.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True")

con.Open()

cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Table](FirstName,LastName,MI,Address,Email) VALUES(@FN,@LN,@MI,@AD,@EM)"
cmd.Connection = con

cmd.Parameters.Add("@FN", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@LN", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@MI", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@AD", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox4.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@EM", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox5.Text

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

MsgBox("Added!")
con.Close()

Me.TableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Database1DataSet.Table)
```

Comment: did you try a profiler trace?

Answer (score 1):

The whole *AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to create your database **on the server** using a management tool (like SSMS Express), give it a logical name (e.g. `MyDatabase`), and then connect to it using its **logical database name** (given when you create it on the server). Don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

```
Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True
```

and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Also see Aaron Betrand's blog post [Bad Habits to Kick - using AttachDbFileName](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/) for more background info